# Magento Toolbar problem with custom Sorting code

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I was trying to Sort product listing with created_at and group by Name, that why i added

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                ->getSelect()->group('name');;
```

before

```
return $this->_productCollection;
```

in `function _getProductCollection()`

//app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/list.php

sorting is working fine but pagination and item quantity showing wrong. 
[image]

It looks like only 1 products but i have much product here and i have not changed anything in toolbar page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have the `group()` statement there. If you don't need it remove it.
In case you need it you have an other issue not related to sorting.
This is a general issue with Magento Collections. The `getSize()` method does not play well with `GROUP BY`.
[Here is one of the solutions](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/01/05/magento-wrong-count-in-admin-grid-when-using-group-by-clause-overriding-lib-module/) (most used one I think)

An other solution (a more elegant one in my opinion) can be extracted from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472702/add-categories-column-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-admin)
The question is about adding the category names to the product grid, but it ends up with the same issue. `getSize()` returns 1.
The main idea with the second solution is to override the method `getSelectCountSql` of the collection you need (in your case the product collection) and let it behave like it usually does when you don't have a `group by` statement and change its behavior when `group by` is involved.